# gradle-release plugin + maven publishing plugin

Tags: deployment, gradle, release, publish, gradle-release-plugin

I'm creating gradle builds as a new gradle user, but I have worked with maven in the past.

I'm trying to reproduce actions of the maven release plugin:

- Change branch version to Release number (commit at svn)
- Create a tag (at svn)
- Deploy the release tag in Nexus OSS
- Change branch version to new Snapshot number (commit at svn)

As you can see, I'm using:

- Nexus OSS as versioning repository
- SVN as scm
- Gradle (2.8)

I'm trying to achieve my objectives with these two plugins:

1. [Gradle-release Plugin](https://github.com/researchgate/gradle-release):

   - Change branch version to Release number (commit at svn)
   - Create a tag (at svn)
   - Change branch version to new Snapshot number (commit at svn)

   Command line: **gradle release**
2. [Maven Publish Plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/publishing_maven.html) to deploy to Nexus:

   Command line: **gradle publish**

**Any ideas how I could generate a release and automatically deploy it to Nexus in one shot?**

Below is my *build.gradle*:

```
plugins {
    id 'net.researchgate.release' version '2.3.4'
}

apply plugin: 'maven-publish'


/*------------------------
----- PUBLISH PLUGIN -----
--------------------------
https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/publishing_maven.html
--------------------------*/
publishing {
    publications {
        maven(MavenPublication) {
            groupId mavenGroup
            artifactId mavenArtifact
            version version

            from components.java
        }
    }
    repositories {
        maven {
            if(project.version.endsWith('-SNAPSHOT')) {
                url "${nexusUrl}/content/repositories/repo-snapshots"
            } else {
                url "${nexusUrl}/content/repositories/repo-releases"
            }
            credentials {
                username nexusUsername
                password nexusPassword
            }
        }
    }
}

/*------------------------
----- RELEASE PLUGIN -----
--------------------------
https://github.com/researchgate/gradle-release
--------------------------*/
release {
    failOnCommitNeeded = false 
    failOnUnversionedFiles = false

    scmAdapters = [
        net.researchgate.release.SvnAdapter
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to setup a dependency between the two tasks. This can be done by adding this line in your `build.gradle`:

```
afterReleaseBuild.dependsOn publish
```

The release-plugin has two tasks which are exactly for the usecase of hooking other tasks in the release process, namely `beforeReleaseBuild` and `afterReleaseBuild`. This tasks (and the dependencies you set) are executed before or respectively after the `build` task.

https://github.com/researchgate/gradle-release#custom-release-steps